# Real world performance of ninja vs msbuild?

Tags: build, msbuild, ninja

I'm thinking about porting a huge C++ and C# code base from msbuild to cmake/ninja based on the promise that ninja has **much** better parallelism than msbuild when it comes to building native code. Does anyone have any real world experience of doing this? I want to know if the cost of porting is actually worth while or not. Ideally before and after build times :)

Also how is that ninja can supposedly be so much faster than msbuild? I assume it must do things like build the objects files of project A and B in parallel even if B needs to link A's output?

Comment: There's an [article](http://www.aosabook.org/en/posa/ninja.html) describing some of what Ninja does to achieve its performance in the book _The Performance of Open Source Applications_. Ninja does have the parallelism you describe (building object files for project A and B in parallel) but that's probably not one of the more significant sources of whatever performance advantage Ninja has over MSBuild.